# JavaFX - Call button events using a keyListener

Tags: javafx, fxml

I looked up some examples/questions to implement a keylistener in JavaFX but every article I found uses only `void typedKey(KeyEvent event){}` instead of using `ActionEvent event` as parameter.
Which appears to be better because I already tried it and it worked...

But the issue is that depending on the key typed there's a call to a method of the JavaFX scene controller.

```
@FXML
void pressedButton0(ActionEvent event){
    String text = txfPrincipal.getText();
    text += "0";
    txfPrincipal.setText(text);
    Operations += "0";
}
```

And because all the methods request an ActionEvent type it can't be called in a switch statement like the following:

```
@FXML
void typedKey(KeyEvent event) {
    switch (event.getCode()) {
        case NUMPAD0:
            pressedButton0(event); //Incompatible type of parameter
        //case NUMPAD1:
        //Case NUMPAD2:
        //...
    }
}
```

And changing `void typedKey(KeyEvent event)` to `void typedKey(ActionEvent event)` (which is what JavaFX was recommending to use...) does not work because it's not meant to get the code of the key typed...

Comment: This is just me guessing what you are trying to do. Give `Button0` an `FX:ID` in the `FXML`. Then replace `pressedButton0(event);` in the switch with `button0'sFX:ID.fire()`.

Comment: Exactly! But btn0.fire() sets two zeros on the textfield instead of one... And I can't find out why.

Comment: That looks like a different issue. Post an answer to this question. Then make an attempt to figure out your current issue. If you can't figure your current issue out, post a new question.

Comment: My guess is that when you press the zero on the number pad, it adds a zero. Then your button fires and adds another.

Comment: Research `EventFilter` to see if that can fix your issue. https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/filters.htm

Comment: [mcve] please..

Comment: Why don’t you define a method with the common functionality and call it from both the button handler and the key listener? You’re not using the event in the button handler, so you don’t need it.